# Flux webhook receiver giving 400 error code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, flux, fluxcd, gitops

H,
I am trying to enable webook for GitHub with flux as mentioned in this link https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/guides/webhook-receivers/. GitHub fails to push the event and gets 400 error code. This is on gcp cluster.
Any pointers to debug this of great help.

On the cluster, I cross-checked controllers are all up and running

-Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue with some setting in the GitRepository names. Now i see the following error when the Push event i sent

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:23.346Z","logger":"receiver-server","msg":"handling request","digest":"cfc7a9a5cd337d1c0f58d5d790eb1f988c3c91ed1201a1b692cf8b479abc62a2"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:23.347Z","logger":"receiver-server","msg":"handling GitHub event: push","receiver":"github-receiver"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:23.347Z","logger":"receiver-server","msg":"found matching receiver","receiver":"github-receiver"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:23.354Z","logger":"receiver-server","msg":"resource annotated","receiver":"github-receiver","resource":"gitrepoinfo"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:23.580Z","logger":"event-server","msg":"Discarding event, no alerts found for the involved object","object":"flux-system/gitrepoinfo","kind":"GitRepository"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-02-22T05:56:24.321Z","logger":"event-server","msg":"Discarding event, no alerts found for the involved object","object":"flux-system/podinfo","kind":"Kustomization"}
```

I added Alert and Provider configuration, then to see the error. Even though events are getting pushed, flux is not picking up changes from repo.
Any pointers would be of great help.

-Prashanth

Comment: Hi, it would help if you share the relevant Yml config files.